# Requirements for supporting the 64bit apps

Tags: android, kotlin, android-ndk, 64-bit

Could somebody explain what does it mean for existing Android 32bit apps?
What should we change or what should we add to the code?

What should I do if my app doesn't use the NDK and any third party libs? I mean, how I should understand a phrase "Apps that do not include native code are unaffected."?

Sorry, if question is stupid but I never coding with 64bit requirements. So I'm in prostration.

Comment: You should understand it exactly as it is written. If your app isn't using native code, then it is not affected (nothing changes). A Google search on *What is Android Native Code?* explains what it is; if you're not using it, you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native code refers to C and C++ (I think C# as well, but Android doesn't support that through the NDK). Those languages are accessed through JNI as natives. Since these are native languages, there are some platform differences. Native languages on desktop devices (windows, mac, linux, etc) usually have natives by os and system architecture (e.g. windows 64 bit). Since android is a single unified system, adding support for windows in your android natives isn't an option. But android natives need support for the core architectures (e.g. x86 and ARM, IIRC there's another set of natives, and support for 32 and 64 bit of those)

If you don't use natives (you use Java or Kotlin, looking aside any libraries that add natives) you don't need to worry about that.